# There are _ beautiful flowers,wish I could have brought camera

Tags: sentence-construction

> There are ____ beautiful flowers. I wish I could have brought a camera.

Answer options given:

> 1. many
> 2. so
> 3. such
> 4. all

My approach:

b) to show extreme feelings or an opinion about something I have used "such" rather than "so" because "so" is used to show fact (usually with a result or consequence).

[Source](http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/So-Such.htm)

I am confused between *many*, *all* and *such*.

Also any better way through which I can analyze the answer better?

Comment: Did you possibly omit a personal pronoun and an article when you copied this question?  It seems to me like it likely originally read: _There are ____ beautiful flowers,_ **I** _wish I could have brought_ **a/the** _camera._  Or did you write this example yourself?

Comment: @Adam No i have not done any omitting.May be the question had error.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems it does.  Without the second half being corrected, one can't be sure on the first half.  For example, this is grammatically correct: _There are **many** beautiful flowers.  I wish I could have brought a camera._   So is this: _There are **such** beautiful flowers, I wish I could have brought a camera._   Note that in one case there is a comma, and in the other a period (two sentences.)

Comment: It seems to me that in "*There are **such** beautiful flowers, I wish...*" something is missing.  I'm inclined to ask "where?".

Comment: I agree, @VictorBazarov.  The rewrites I gave still aren't natural-sounding sentences, but they are at least grammatical.  (OP:  I can imagine a situation where "could have brought a camera" is correct, but I can imagine many more in which the correct conjugation of _bring_ would be: _I wish I **had** brought a camera_)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the question in the source you provide, but as it stands it's terribly and confusingly formatted. It probably should be something like:

> These are ____ beautiful flowers, I wish I could have brought my camera

And in that case I *think* what they're looking for is for you to know how to avoid a comma splice. The correct answer would be 3:

> "These are **such** beautiful flowers, I wish I could have brought my camera

instead of (with the comma splice):

> "These are **all** beautiful flowers, I wish I could have brought my camera

The reason I think the first word should be "These" and not "There" is because if the latter is used, then *none* of the answers offered makes for a particularly well-constructed sentence.

Comment: If you were talking about some specific flowers then you'd use "These." However if you were at a flower and garden show then "There" would be appropriate. At the flower and garden show "There" would not only include the flowers which were currently being observed, but the flowers that were seen earlier.

Comment: I agree, but only if the context is explained. So *"There are many beautiful flowers* **at the flower and garden show** *..."* would work. Without that extra context, using "There" is not strictly wrong, but I don't think a native speaker would use it.